# How can I get the alias name for my ResultSet from a Subquery?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, alias, resultset

I have a problem with getting the alias of the columnnames for my ResultSet.
I made a subquery, where i use the alias function(MAX(...) in SQL) but everytime I execute the Statement, I get `java.sql.SQLException` because the column name is not valid. And I use the current alias where I call the `getString` - Function of my ResultSet.

This is my SQL-Statement in Eclipse:

```
String sql = "SELECT   a.steelgrade, a.prod_order_id, a.prod_order_item_pos, "
                        +"a.prod_order_version, a.strip_thickn_aim, a.strip_width_aim, "
                        +"a.customer, a.order_weight_plan, b.grund_kommlos, b.coil_weight "
                        +"FROM (SELECT   prod_order_id, prod_order_item_pos, "
                          + "MAX (prod_order_version) AS max_version "
                     + "FROM production_order "
```

And in the ResultSet `while.next()`-Loop:

```
prod_order_version = AuftraegeProduction.getString("max_version");
```

This is the whole SQL-Statement( in the Database it works fine!):

```
SELECT   a.steelgrade, a.prod_order_id, a.prod_order_item_pos,
     a.prod_order_version, a.strip_thickn_aim, a.strip_width_aim,
     a.customer, a.order_weight_plan, b.grund_kommlos, b.coil_weight
FROM (SELECT   prod_order_id, prod_order_item_pos,
               MAX (prod_order_version) AS max_version
          FROM production_order
GROUP BY prod_order_id, prod_order_item_pos) c
     JOIN
     production_order a
     ON a.prod_order_id = c.prod_order_id
   AND a.prod_order_item_pos = c.prod_order_item_pos
   AND a.prod_order_version = c.max_version
     JOIN pps_plan_slab b
     ON b.prod_order_id = c.prod_order_id
   AND b.prod_order_item_pos = c.prod_order_item_pos
   AND b.prod_order_version = c.max_version
WHERE a.strip_thickn_aim > 1.78
 AND a.strip_thickn_aim < 3.26
 AND a.steelgrade = 'M4R51'
 AND a.prod_order_id NOT BETWEEN '0999551' AND '0999599'
 AND a.strip_width_aim BETWEEN 1126 AND 1166
 AND NVL (a.order_weight_plan, 0) > 0
 AND a.order_weight_plan >= b.coil_weight
ORDER BY prod_order_id ASC
```

Anyone have a suggestion?

Maurice

Comment: Did you try to run the query manually, directly in the DB ? it seems like it's missing something... maybe `group by` ? By the way, it would be appreciated if you'd tag the DB you're using...

Comment: Yes, i executed the Statement in the DB before to check if everything is right with my SQL-Query. And in the DB, however it works! I use an Oracle DB in this case.

Comment: First, you're missing a closing bracket - so no way it could be ran "as is". Second, can you really run: `SELECT   prod_order_id, prod_order_item_pos, MAX (prod_order_version) AS max_version FROM production_order` without grouping? Maybe I didn't touch Oracle DB for too long...

Comment: I've made a "GROUP BY", but still doesn't work: "...GROUP BY prod_order_id, prod_order_item_pos) c

Comment: As I already wrote  in my initial comment: first make the query run on the DB, *then* start worrying about making it work with your code!

Comment: On my DB it works fine, the Problem is to fetch the Data from my ResultSet with the correct column name.. if i use 'prod_order_verison' instead of the alias for my column name , it works. But it's not the result that i want.

Comment: you open a bracket after the first `FROM` and never close it. For the last time, the query in the code that you posted - cannot possibly work. So if you want some help - you'll have to help us help you. It's half past midnight here, so I'm giving up and calling it a day, but maybe someone else will be able to help you...

Comment: I'm a newbie , sorry ^^ But thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

when using aggregate functions max(),min(),sum(),... you must use group by clause clause.

Comment: OK, i've edited the SQL-Statement so far: 'code'  String sql2 =  "SELECT   a.steelgrade, a.prod_order_id, a.prod_order_item_pos, "
              +"a.prod_order_version, a.strip_thickn_aim, a.strip_width_aim, "
              +"a.customer, a.order_weight_plan, b.grund_kommlos, b.coil_weight "
       +"FROM (SELECT   prod_order_id, prod_order_item_pos, "
                     + "MAX (prod_order_version) AS max_version "
                + "FROM production_order "
            + "GROUP BY prod_order_id, prod_order_item_pos) c "

Comment: this will throw an error also because group by is not allowed in subquery. give us the requirements and table structure in order to help you re-structure your query.

Comment: i just edited my question, there you can see the whole sql statement which works on oracle DB